# TfsTeamProjectCollection API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm using the TFS API to connect to Team Foundation Server. In the Server URI , I'm passing the hostname of the server.
Me getting a Bad URI format error.

teamFoundationServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(this.Server,UriKind.Absolute), this.Credentials);
teamFoundationServer.EnsureAuthenticated();

Comment: 1. What is this.Server? A string? What's the value? 2. Can you post the Stacktrace?

Comment: Consider this
teamFoundationServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfs.server.com",UriKind.Absolute),credentials<object>)

Answer (score 5):

I think you need the URL of the Team Project Collection, not just the server, probably:

```
http://server:8080/tfs/collection
```

There is an example of connecting on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx) but it iterates through all the project collections on the TFS instance, but with that example code you could examine [TfsTeamProjectCollection.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconnection.uri.aspx) to confirm the correct URI to use.